# How to connect amazon RDS database using php

Tags: php, sql, amazon-rds

I get this error when I try to connect to the mysql database using php mysqli class.

I am using
OS        :- windows 10
webserver :- xampp
php       :- 7.3.3

it got a warning error and error message is junk.

> mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002):
>   �ڑ��ς݂̌Ăяo���悪���̎��Ԃ�߂��Ă������������Ȃ��������߁A�ڑ��ł��܂���ł����B�܂��͐ڑ��ς݂̃z�X�g���������Ȃ��������߁A�m�����ꂽ�ڑ��͎��s���܂����

Using following code:

```
$dbServerName= "*******ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
$dbUsername= "example";
$dbPassword= "*******";
$dbName= "example";



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

dbServerName is amazon.com for example,
password is * for security.

Comment: Your server name looks totally bogus to me.  You need to use the actual IP/connection information which you get from the AWS console.

Comment: Agree with @TimBiegeleisen, AWS RDS based links are like ******.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com. (your region may vary depending on your instance)

Comment: I use this IP/connection like *******ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com .The symbol **** will be a project name.

Comment: check whether it is connected through terminal.